# WICD WPA2-PEAP connection without domain

Tags: wireless, encryption, wicd, wpa2

I'm having trouble connecting to my school's wifi.  It uses WPA2-PEAP and TKIP.  The instructions for connecting tell me to leave the domain field blank and just enter my user name and password.  This works with network-manager, but WICD tells me that the domain is required.  I assume I need to edit an encryption script some where, but I wouldn't know what to change.  How can I connect to this network?  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with wicd, I suggest you file a bug report. What happens if you enter a space for a domain name ? And what is wrong with using network manager?

Comment: I'll submit a bug report.  If I enter a space, I get a bad password error and can't connect.  Network-manager doesn't play well with the network in my apartment, keeps disconnecting me.

Comment: painful, I have had that problem before. only other suggestion I have would be knetworkmanager.

Comment: I figured it out.  I edited the WPA2-PEAP template, removed all references to domain, saved it under a new name and added it to the active file.  Now it doesn't even ask for a domain and connects just fine.  I'll post the encryption template when I'm allowed to answer my own question (come on really?) in 6 hours.

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but as promised, here's the edited encryption template.

```
name = TUSecure
author = atiketemola
version = 1
require identity *Username password *Password
protected password *Password
-----
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
network={
    ssid="$_ESSID"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP
    eap=PEAP
    identity="$_IDENTITY"
    password="$_PASSWORD"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPv2"
}
```

Comment: Note to the naysayers: **this is the solution to the problem**, it's not a revision of the problem.

Comment: Pointer to future arrivals: the encryption templates are found in `/etc/wicd/encryption/templates`, and once you've made a new template you need to add it to `/etc/wicd/encryption/templates/active` and restart wicd.